# Azure security - Hardening of O/S builds, security standards?

Tags: azure

This is a question for Azure experts, in particular around the Windows VM's available in Azure.

Do they make any changes to the base build? Hardening and security standards? Or are they standard builds fresh out the box?

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

yes. Public and up-to-date information about security measures like compliance, some technical details, etc, can be found on the [Azure Trust Center](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/trust-center/).

However, i do not think that Microsoft reveals all of the internal implementation information, but a lot of work is doing around isolation of hypervisor, root os, guest vms. Also, there is the Azure Fabric Controller is the "brain" that secures and isolates customer deployments and manage the commands sent to Host OS/Hypervisor, and the Host OS is a *configuration-hardened* version of Windows Server.

Some basic information can be found here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud/gg663906.aspx

Azure Fabric Controller: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/fabric-controller-internals-building-and-updating-high-availability-apps/

And i recommend to follow [Mark Russinovich](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/speakers/mark-russinovich), Azure CTO, as his video are one of the most internal-details-revealing i ever saw.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check out the CIS hardened Images in the Azure Marketplace: https://www.cisecurity.org/cis-hardened-images-now-in-microsoft-azure-marketplace/

Ther you can choose between two levels of hardening, depending on your workload as well as there multiple Windows Server versiosn and even some Linuxs distrubutions. If you want to harden the VMs yourself, I would check out the Dev-Sec Project on github: https://github.com/dev-sec

There you can customize the hardening to your needs if you have an automation tool in place like chef, puppet etc.